# Controlling JW FLV player with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer

I'm trying to control an instance of the [JW FLV player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) player using jquery.

What I want to do is have a series of links which when clicked load an XML playlist into the player.

By following the tutorial [here](http://home5.inet.tele.dk/nyboe/flash/mediaplayer4/JW_API_xmpl_5-2-3-0.html) I've gotten things working basically as I want them in terms of functionality, but even I can see that it's ugly as sin, as at the moment my anchors look like this:

```
<a class="media" href="#"
onclick="player.sendEvent('STOP');
player.sendEvent('LOAD',
'path/to/playlist.xml');
return false;">load playlist</a>
```

while this gets a ref to the player

```
var player = null;
function playerReady(obj)
{
  player = gid(obj.id);
};

function gid(name)
{
  return document.getElementById(name);
};
```

What I'd like to be able to do is have my anchors look like this:

```
<a class="media" href="#" rel="path/to/playlist.xml">load playlist</a>
```

And then use jquery to find the anchors with class="media", read the value of the element's rel attribute and then bind a click event to it which triggers an appropriate function. Alas this is beyond my extremely meagre powers.

So far I've got:

```
$('a.media').click(function()
  {
    playlist = $(this).attr("rel");
    player.sendEvent('LOAD', playlist
  }
);
```

Which clearly doesn't work. Anyone care to help an idiot/n00b?

I should say that really what I want to do is *learn* rather than just get some one else to do it, so if you can explain things a bit that would be extra awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing seems correct to me, although I'm not sure variable "player" is defined there; it depends on the context.

What you can do is something like

```
$('a.media').click(function () {
  var player = $("#player-id");
  if(player.length == 1){
    player = player[0];
    var playlist = $(this).attr("rel");
    player.sendEvent('LOAD', playlist);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
player.sendEvent('LOAD', playlist
}
);
```

Check your bracket nesting.

Otherwise, should work. But ‘rel’ isn't a very good place to put a URL, as it is only supposed to contain [known tokens](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#adef-rel). Why not put it in ‘href’ where you would expect? You just have to ‘return false’ or ‘preventDefault’ to stop the link being followed after a lick.

```
function playerReady(obj)
{
    player = gid(obj.id);
};
function gid(name)
{
    return document.getElementById(name);
};
```

Er, isn't gid completely superfluous here? Why not just ‘player= obj’?

Comment: thanks bobince - it's always the simple things.. I was going to use the href to point to an alternative page that would load a player with the same playlist for users with js disabled (passing the playlist string in the url), but I'm guessing I could just parse the href value for the segment I need?

Comment: the playerReady function was a dirty cut'n'paste job from the tutorial I'm afraid. As I say I'm just starting out with this stuff. could you maybe explain a little more and suggest something better? cheers, meta

Answer (score 0):

I'm get the same problem like you here. And I realize that the first you call create player using

```
var newplayer = SWFobject(width,height,playerid,version,background-color);
newplayer.addVarible(...);
newplayer.write(htmltaghold place for this player);
```

I don't remember correctly but its like the code above, after that you can use var player = window.document[thePlayer.id] in the function playerReady(thePlayer){} in jQuery
like

```
jQuery("div#id").click(function(){
   your code
   player.sendEvent("NEXT");
});
```

player.sendEvent("PLAY"); ..etc. Hope we can talk about that and improve jQuery